# What event does angularjs use to get a value from text input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What event  does angularjs use to get a value from text input? I thought it's oninput or onchange.

Comment: Do you come from a jQuery background ?
To get a value from a text input, angularjs uses ng-model.
I suggest you look up angularjs basics such as double binding.

Comment: I am not about basics. I want to know What way does angularjs use to get a value?

Comment: it's every keypress. For every keypress the scope changes.

Comment: Please, give an example of event.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the `input` event is supported and not IE9 
   listen for the `input` event 
   otherwise listen for the `keydown`, `paste`, `cut` events
2. Listen for the `change` event